# how can wo microservices communicate every minute with shared database,?

Tags: python, flask

I want to create two microservices in python, one posts data into the database every minute and the other will process the data once it's posted into the database. I would like to know what would be an ideal architecture for this? How can this be done in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like something that should be solved using the CQRS pattern. One service is responsible for updating the database and the other one is responsible for utilizing the data. This way you are separating the update and read operations making it very scalable.

I'm a big fan of an event-driven architecture when it makes sense, and since you are talking about RabbitMQ in your first solution, then I would probably continue down that path.

I would use two different topic types. One for commands and one for events. Commands would be things like "update entity" or whatever makes sense in your case. The events are things that happened like "entity updated". Your first service should subscribe to the relevant commands and send out an event after the operation is complete. The second service would subscribe to that event and do the processing that it is supposed to do.

Also a quick note on message queues. There are a lot of different message queues out there. RabbitMQ is a solid but old choice so you might benefit from one of the other options. I personally like Kafka a lot but things like Redis or the ones provided by cloud services like Azure or AWS along with many others.